# JavaScript user tracking without sending data away

Tags: logging, javascript

To be able to do detailed user tracking (JS interaction, not just link logs) while preserving privacy, I'm looking for something like Google Analytics that stores all the data locally.

Answer (score 1):

[Mint](http://www.haveamint.com/) is one of the most popular self hosted analytics packages, i've used it a couple of times and it's an excellent tool.